# Convert string through hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I'm trying to convert a string of morse code into words. I split the string into words. Then I split each word into a secondary array of letters and numbers.

```
 def self.decode(str)
    decoded = ""
    arr = []
    p arr = str.split('  ')
    p arr.map! { |i| i.split('  ') }

    arr.each do |r|
      r.each do |i|
          decoded += @morse.invert[i].to_s[-1]
      end
    end

    p decoded
end
```

In my [hash](http://pastebin.com/gCJ1pgT3), I use numbers. They start with `N`. In `to_s[-1]`, the `-1` is to drop the `N`.

I get this error:

```
`+': no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

I can figure out how to get past it though because I don't see a `nil` value in the array.

```
class Morse

    @morse = {
        A: '.-',
        B: '-...',
        C: '-.-.',
        D: '-..',
        E: '.',
        F: '..-.',
        G: '--.',
        H: '....',
        I: '..',
        J: '.---',
        K: '-.-',
        L: '.-..',
        M: '--',
        N: '-.',
        O: '---',
        P: '.--.',
        Q: '--.-',
        R: '.-.',
        S: '...',
        T: '-',
        U: '..-',
        V: '...-',
        W: '.--',
        X: '-..-',
        Y: '-.--',
        Z: '--..',
        ' ': ' ' ,
        N1: '.----',
        N2: '..---',
        N3: '...--',
        N4: '....-',
        N5: '.....',
        N6: '-....',
        N7: '--...',
        N8: '---..',
        N9: '----.',
        N0: '-----'
    }

def self.encode(str)
    encoded = ""
    sym_temp = ""
    str = str.upcase!
    str.each_char do |c|
        ascii_check = c.ord
        if ascii_check.between?(65,90)
            temp = str[c].to_sym
            encoded += "#{@morse[temp]}" + " "
        elsif ascii_check.between?(48,57)   
            temp = "N".concat(str[c]).to_sym
            encoded += "#{@morse[temp]}" + " "
        elsif ascii_check ===(32)
            temp = str[c].to_sym
            encoded += "#{@morse[temp]}"
        end
    end
    p encoded
end

def self.decode(str)
    decoded = ""
    arr = []
    # str.split('  ').map do |i|
    p arr = str.split('  ')
    p arr.map! { |i| i.split('  ') }

    arr.each do |r|
      r.each do |i|
        p  decoded += @morse.invert[i].to_s[-1].to_s
      end
    end             

    p decoded
end

# def self.read_file
    # # @Temp = File.read("preamble_encode.txt").chomp
      # # File.open('hiscore.txt'){|f| f.lines.map{|l| l.chomp!.split(',')}}
    # # @Temp = File.foreach("preamble_encode.txt", 'r') {|f| f.lines.map{|l| l.chomp}}

# end

# def self.write_file
    # # Temp2 = File.open('preamble_decode.txt', 'w') do |f|
        # # f.puts Temp2
    # # end
# end

end


test = "Abc 1oL!"
test2 = ".-- .  - .... .  .--. . --- .--. .-.. ."
Morse.encode(test)
Morse.decode(test2)
```

Comment: Do one thing to track it quickly. Change the adding logic as follows:

decoded += @morse.invert[i].to_s[-1].to_s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
        :P => :'.--.',
```

Your colon on the right hand side of the hash rocket is making that a symbol, not a string.  As it happens, your test case for decode includes a P.  When you try to look up the *String* '.--.', it doesn't find it and returns nil.

Comment: Good eyes! :)  This typo could probably have been avoided by using the newer hash key/value notation, in this case `P: '.--.'`.  The double colon would have stood out and been easy to spot.

Comment: Thanks, also updated my code a bit now, it still doesn't seem to put anything in decoded, but at least it isn't giving me that error!

Answer (score 3):

As you question has been answered, I would like to suggest how you may write methods for coding and decoding.

Firstly, the keys of your hash should be strings rather than symbols, as the hash is being used to code strings, which are made up of single-character strings. We also need the digits to be, `'0'` to `'9'` rather than `'N0'` to `'N9'`. Spaces are represented by time delays equal to seven dots, rather than combinations of dots and dashes, so I've represented spaces by the string `'<delay>'`. See the [Morse Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code).

Since the hash won't change, I've made it a constant rather than the value of an instance variable.

```
CharactersToMorse = {
  'A' => '.-', 'B' => '-...', 'C' => '-.-.', 'D' => '-..', 'E' => '.', 'F' => '..-.',
  'G' => '--.', 'H' => '....', 'I' => '..', 'J' => '.---', 'K' => '-.-', 'L' => '.-..',
  'M' => '--' , 'N' => '-.', 'O' => '---', 'P' => '.--.', 'Q' => '--.-', 'R' => '.-.',
  'S' => '...', 'T' => '-', 'U' => '..-', 'V' => '...-', 'W' => '.--', 'X' => '-..-',
  'Y' => '-.--', 'Z' => '--..' , ' ' => '<delay>', '0' => '-----', '1' => '.----',
  '2' => '..---', '3' => '...--', '4' => '....-', '5' => '.....', '6' => '-....',
  '7' => '--...', '8' => '---..', '9' => '----.'
}
```

We will need to decode, so I'll assign the inverted hash to a constant as well.

```
MorseToCharacters = CharactersToMorse.invert
  #=> {".-"=>"A", "-..."=>"B", "-.-."=>"C", "-.."=>"D", "."=>"E", "..-."=>"F",
  #    "--."=>"G", "...."=>"H", ".."=>"I", ".---"=>"J", "-.-"=>"K", ".-.."=>"L",
  #    "--"=>"M", "-."=>"N", "---"=>"O", ".--."=>"P", "--.-"=>"Q", ".-."=>"R",
  #    "..."=>"S", "-"=>"T", "..-"=>"U", "...-"=>"V", ".--"=>"W", "-..-"=>"X",
  #    "-.--"=>"Y", "--.."=>"Z", "<delay>"=>" ", "-----"=>"0", ".----"=>"1", "..---"=>"2",
  #    "...--"=>"3", "....-"=>"4", "....."=>"5", "-...."=>"6", "--..."=>"7",
  #    "---.."=>"8", "----."=>"9"}
```

Our methods for coding and decoding are now very simple.

```
def code(text)
  text.each_char.map { |c| CharactersToMorse[c] }
end

def decode(morse)
  morse.map { |m| MorseToCharacters[m] }.join(' ')
end
```

Let's try it.

```
text = "NOW IS THE TIME FOR 47 RUBIESTS TO COME TO THE AID OF THEIR BOWLING TEAM"

morse = code(text)
  #=> ["-.", "---", ".--", "<delay>", "..", "...", "<delay>", "-", "....",
  #    ".", "<delay>", "-", "..", "--", ".", "<delay>", "..-.", "---", ".-.",
  #    "<delay>", "....-", "--...", "<delay>", ".-.", "..-", "-...", "..",
  #    ".", "...", "-", "...", "<delay>", "-", "---", "<delay>", "-.-.", "---",
  #    "--", ".", "<delay>", "-", "---", "<delay>", "-", "....", ".", "<delay>",
  #    ".-", "..", "-..", "<delay>", "---", "..-.", "<delay>", "-", "....",
  #    ".", "..", ".-.", "<delay>", "-...", "---", ".--", ".-..", "..", "-.",
  #    "--.", "<delay>", "-", ".", ".-", "--"] 

decode(morse)
  #=> "NOW IS THE TIME FOR 47 RUBIESTS TO COME TO THE AID OF THEIR BOWLING TEAM"
```

If for some reason the keys of `CharactersToMorse` must be symbols, change the methods to:

```
def code(text)
  text.each_char.map { |c| CharactersToMorse[c.to_sym] }
end

def decode(morse)
  morse.map { |m| MorseToCharacters[m].to_s }.join(' ')
end
```

Comment: Looking at it like that makes it seem sooo simple, and I wish I could use strings... but this is an assignment where they must be symbols. But This is actually really nice to see and I'll be keeping this in mind if something like this comes up again!

Comment: It's a minor change if the keys are symbols. I've added an explanation at the end of my answer.

Comment: There is still a small confusion on how to make the numbers work then since I don't believe 1: or 1=> works?

Comment: @Alex `:'1'` is a valid symbol. Within a hash, you can use `{:'1' => '·−−−−'}` or `{'1': '·−−−−'}` (requires Ruby 2.2 or newer)

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. I've rolled back. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland sorry about the late response, power outage. First off thanks so much for all the help. Second, the assignment specifies that I would need to take from a file and print to a file, so printing the array of arrays doesn't really suit so I'm trying to join the strings together. but I am having a little trouble getting it to accept the map of strings, also would it be possible to take in a string of morse code and then map it for the decode method?

Comment: Alex, if you are given `@morse` by your assignment is there any reason you cannot define `@chars_to_morse = @morse.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k.to_s[-1]] = v }`, then `@morse_to_chars = @chars_to_morse.invert`?

Comment: In relation to the assignment, probably not, but in relation to myself and my level of knowledge, yes. Everything you just wrote just flew over my head a bit..

Comment: @CarySwoveland anyways thanks you again for the explanations, things seem to be working.